# Sorting elements of catalog

Tags: php, sorting

I use the function `readdir` and select files in directory. I read files in rotation and write them to the database.
But files rotating in random, and file, which was created earlier can write after file, which created later.
How I can read files, sorting them by date of creation? I can do this easy? Without the use of arrays and sorting files there, etc...

```
if ($dir_handle = opendir ($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle))) {
        if (is_file($dir.$file_name)){
                        ...............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily read files sorted by date of creation, without using arrays and other calls to get creation date and sorting them... well I suppose you could make an `exec()` call instead, but that's frowned upon...

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the date of creation of each file to the DB, and then sort it when you SELECT:

`SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY create_date DESC`